# How can I check character occurrence in a string?

Tags: java, string

My Question is-

Input is string. Return true if the String has exactly 1 character that appears twice in the string, 0 character that appear thrice in the string, and at least 1 character that appear four or more times in the string. There is a problem in my code and I am unable to find out the problem.

```
public class CheckCharacterOccurence {

    static String testcase1 = "jjiiiiyy";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckCharacterOccurence testInstance = new CheckCharacterOccurence();
        boolean result = testInstance.checkCharacterOccurence(testcase1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public boolean checkCharacterOccurence(String str) {
        char ch=' ';
        char ch1=' ';
        int temp=0;
        int temp1=0;
        int temp2=0;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            ch=str.charAt(i);
            for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++){
                if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)){
                    ch1=str.charAt(i);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            if(count==2&&ch!=ch1){
                temp++;
            }
            if(count==3&&ch!=ch1){
                temp1++;
            }
            if(count>=4){
                temp2++;
            }
            count=0;
        }
        if(temp==1&&temp1==0&&temp2>=1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a question, that's a homework assignment accompanied with code and a useless "something is wrong" comment. What's the code doing if it's not working right?

Comment: Smells like homework. Are you looking for hints or answers? What specific error do you see?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
For all characters in string, increment map[that_char]

At last iterate over map to find how many times each character appeared.

Alternatively you can use array also to keep count.

Something like

```
int [] ctr = new int[256]
ctr = all zeroes
for (ch : string)
  ctr[ch]++

mxocc = 0
maxch = 'a'
for(ch = a, b, c, d, e...) 
  if(ctr[ch] > maxocc) maxocc = ctr[ch] and maxch = ch 
Output require info
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can figure out the problem ... atleast i can give to some extend same code , you can check it and try to solve your problem... This program finds the pattern in the string, now you can go through this program, and try to solve ur problem in your program by your own self.and try to do it by your own then only ur coding skills will get improved.and vote this answer if u fing it really helpful

```
          #include<stdio.h>
          #include<string.h>

          int occur(char[],char[]);

          int occur(char sent[],char pattern[])
            {

          int count=0;

          for(int i=0,j=i;sent[i]!='\0';)
           {
        if(sent[i+j]==pattern[j]&&pattern[j]!='\0')
         {
         j++;


         }
               else if(j==strlen(pattern))
           {
           count++;
           i=i+j;
           j=0;
           }
         else
          {
        i++;
        j=0;

          }

         }
  return count;
 }

    int main()
    {
   char sent[] = "aabaabaaabbbabababddfggaabbbasab";
   char pattern[] = "aba";
   int result = occur(sent,pattern);
   printf("\nNo of Occurrences --- > %d",result);
   return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your code. For example there is not need to use those complex for-loops, you can use a for-each.
This code finds out the frequency of characters in a string and stores it in a Map.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CheckCharacterOccurence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<Character, Integer> counting = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
      String testcase1 = "Helloooo";
      for(char ch: testcase1.toCharArray()){
        Integer freq = counting.get(ch);
        counting.put(ch, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
      }
      System.out.println(counting.size() + " distinct characters:");
      System.out.println(counting);
    }

}
```